# How do I extract a value from a varchar column?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an SQL Server 2008 database with a table that has a column `Data` that contains values like this:

```
Hello\How\Are\You"
```

Each string in that column has 4 blocks (ie. 3 slash bars)

**Question:**

How can I extract, using TSQL, the 3rd value (in this case `Are`) from that column ?

Note that I just care about the 3rd value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [parsename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) and
[replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx).

```
declare @S varchar(30) = 'Hello\How\Are\You'

select parsename(replace(@S, '\', '.'), 2)
```

Comment: Fantastic, never knew about the `parsename` function

Comment: It splits on `.` so therefore the need for replace and it only works if you have four parts (or less).

Comment: more than fantastic :--) Thanks Mikael

Comment: Also requires all the component parts to be `<=` 128 chars or will return `NULL`

Comment: @MikaelEriksson it is a dangerous way of handling the data, there are alot of 'if's'. What if the varchar contains period, what if there are a different number of elements than 4 (it counts from right)

Answer (score 1):

if your data is of a more tricky nature, this is one way of doing it:

```
declare @t1 table(a nvarchar(500))
insert @t1 values('hello/how/are/you')

select left(t2.b, charindex('/', t2.b + '/') - 1)
from @t1 t1
cross apply (select stuff(a,1, charindex('/',a, charindex('/',a) + 1), '') b) t2
```